# How to send/detect a reference/flag to a specific activity from another

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How can I send or detect a reference or flag if a specific `Activity` was started from another `Activity` or not? I actually need a form in which I can execute only a certain piece of code only if this code was called by a specific `Activity`, for example:

**Activity 1:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ranking.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity2:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ranking.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Ranking.class (It's pseudocode since I don't really know how/what to do)**:

```
if(I was called by Activity  1) {
    //do something
} else {
     finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `.putExtra` a message to your `Intent`.

**Activity 1**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ranking.class);
intent.putExtra("activity", 1);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity 2**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ranking.class);
intent.putExtra("activity", 2);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Ranking.class**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int activityNumber = intent.getIntExtra("activity", 0);

if (activityNumber == 1) {
    //do something
} else{
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @israel-dela-cruz is correct, you need to use `extra` to differentiate the flags. Here the more compact version to avoid using **magic number** and **magic key**:

```
public class RankingActivity extends Activity {

  private static final ACTIVITY_OPTION_KEY = "activityOptionKey";
  private static final int FROM_ACTIVITY_ONE = 1;
  private static final int FROM_ACTIVITY_TWO = 2;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);

     ...

     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtra();
     int option = bundle.getInt(ACTIVITY_OPTION_KEY);

     if(option == FROM_ACTIVITY_ONE) {
       // do something when called from activity one
     } else if(option == FROM_ACTIVITY_TWO) {
       // do something when called from activity two
     } else {
       // is there something else?
     }

     ...
  }

  // Use intent factory to remove dependency to magic number and magic key
  public static Intent createIntentFromActivityOne(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RatingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ACTIVITY_OPTION_KEY, FROM_ACTIVITY_ONE);
    return intent;
  }

  public static Intent createIntentFromActivityTwo(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RatingActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ACTIVITY_OPTION_KEY, FROM_ACTIVITY_TWO);
    return intent;
  }
}
```

then you can create the intent without knowing the `RatingActivity` magic key and magic number:

```
// from activity one
Intent intent = RatingActivity.createIntentFromActivityOne(this);
startActivity(intent);

// from activity two
Intent intent = RatingActivity.createIntentFromActivityTwo(this);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: One question. Why are yo using this compact version, instead of using the version of @israel-dela-cruz? what are the advantages?

Comment: @Janzek: It's because tracking the string key for `intent.putExtra("activity", 1);` is so error prone. Especially if you're starting the activity from multiple places. You always need to make sure there is no single error in each activity. For example, when you've a typo for the key; using `activty` instead of `activity`, you end up wasting your time chasing for the bug. How about 3 keys? or even 5 keys? Now, that's the real problem.